# ASP.NET - Get the Principal / Relative Identifier (RID) for a DirectoryEntry / SID

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, sid

I am using Active Directory in a custom MembershipProvider class to authenticate users in an ASP.NET 2.0 intranet application and associate their sid with a profile for the application.

When the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` is used, the `ProviderUserKey` object for the `MembershipUser` is as follows

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
string sidValue = sid.ToString();

/* sidValue = "S-1-5-21-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-YY"  */
```

As I understand it, `YY` is the principal within the namespace (also referred to as a group/domain).

When using the custom MembershipProvider, I can get the sid using the `objectSid` property of a DirectoryEntry object

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password);
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])entry.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
string sidValue = sid.ToString();

/* sidValue = "S-1-5-21-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"  */
```

The `sidValue` in this case is identical, except it does not contain the principal `YY`.

My question is two-fold

1. Is the principal required in order to uniquely identify an individual?
2. Is it possible to obtain the principal from the DirectoryEntry object (or through any other classes available in `System.DirectoryServices`)?

**EDIT:**

Having done some further reading ([{1}](http://www.rlmueller.net/ComputerSIDs.htm) [{2}](http://chantilly.computertraining.edu/index.php/guid-vs-sid)), I now know that the sid can change if the user is moved from one group/domain to another. In light of this, would using the `GUID` defined in the `DirectoryEntry` `Properties["objectGUID"]` be a better choice for uniquely identifying a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objectGUID is the best choice for identifying a user **account**.  I highlight this because the objectGUID is unique and fixed for an instance of an account.  If you delete and recreate the account with the same distinguishedName you'll get a different objectGUID.  So, objectGUID doesn't identify the user, it identifies the account.

So, if you want to identify the account, use objectGUID.

Sometimes, accounts can be deleted and recreated by admins to solve problems.  If you need to identify the user even after this has happened, you need to pick something else on the account object.  That will probably have to depend on your account definition policies.  Maybe you have sAMAccountNames that are not based on the user's name?  Maybe the admins populate employeeid or employeeNumber?  Maybe they enforce uniqueness for displayNames?

Here's a link to [AD attribute info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(VS.85).aspx).
Here's a link to [DirectoryEntry Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry_properties.aspx).

Comment: Is the objectGUID a GUID for the account or a GUID for the type of object that the directory entry represents? Also, Do you have a link to any documentation that provides details on each of the Directory Entry properties?

Comment: It's a GUID for the individual account.  You can see it in Active Directory if you use the ADSI Edit MMC Snap-in (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: I've added links to the main post as the previous one seemed to get a bit mangled.  I wasn't sure whether you wanted the properties of the DirectoryEntry object or the AD object.  In the latter case AD people tend to talk about them as attributes.  So an instance of an AD class, such as user, has attributes such as displayName.  An instance of DirectoryEntry has a Properties property which contains a collection of attributes and their values.  It should be called Attributes, IMO.

Comment: Is there any object-GUID like thing for windows accounts?

Comment: If you mean local accounts on Windows machines (as opposed to Active Directory accounts), then no, there isn't.  But you've still got the SID you can use.